# CPU Loongson works with Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, cpu, support, chinese

Ubuntu supports that CPU?
Someone tried how works?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loongson

Comment: Do you have a particular processor model in mind?

Comment: You can always boot the system to a Live USB of Ubuntu and test if it works or not on that CPU.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu

Comment: Loongson is a MIPS64 CPU. Ubuntu does not currently offer a packaged distribution for the MIPS architecture 

Comment: Why don't have?